# Get PHPUnit Autocomplete in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

I'm struggling to get IntelliJ IDEA to index the PHPUnit.phar for autocompletion. I have added the parent directory to my include path and IDEA is showing it in the project sidebar, but still no autocomplete.

I ended up extracting the .phar in that same directory and that worked fine. Also, I am unable to "view" .phar files the same way I could in PHPStorm.

Any ideas cause I am not a big fan of keeping the extracted .phar files?